# for_each with locals based on condition

Tags: terraform

I have locals I'd like to iterate on:

```
locals {
    url = {
        "https://url1" = { alarm_name = "url1 down", period = "120", threshold = "1", evaluation_periods = "2" },
        "https://url2" = { alarm_name = "url2 down", period = "120", threshold = "1", evaluation_periods = "2" },
        "https://url3" = { alarm_name = "url3 down", period = "120", threshold = "1", evaluation_periods = "2" }
    }
}
```

in my resource I'd like to iterate only if condition/variable equals value:

```
resource "aws_cloudwatch_metric_alarm" "url_down" {
  for_each                  = local.url != null && var.aws_env == "env" ? toset([true]) : toset([])
  alarm_name                = each.value.alarm_name
  evaluation_periods        = each.value.evaluation_periods
  period                    = each.value.period
  threshold                 = each.value.threshold
  alarm_description         = each.value.alarm_name
  dimensions = {
    URL = each.key
  }
... shortened for brevity
}
```

but I am getting an error:

```
The given "for_each" argument value is unsuitable: "for_each" supports maps and sets of strings, but you have provided a set containing type bool
```

Is it possible to build such a logic?

Comment: You're missing a bunch of configuration, such as `comparison_operator` and `metric_name` https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/cloudwatch_metric_alarm#example-usage

Comment: @Paolo: No, I am not missing anything I shortened it for brevity

Comment: The error is pretty clear: you're passing `for_each` a `set(bool)` but it requires a `set(string)`. Have you tried passing a `set(string)` instead, e.g. replacing `toset([true])` with something like `toset(["true"])`?

Comment: @Adrian why would you want to use `toset(["true"])` ?

Comment: @Adrian, no that doesn't work either. `set(string)` is throwing `A reference to a resource type must be followed by at least one attribute access, specifying the resource name.` error while `toset(["true"])` gives `Can't access attributes on a primitive-typed value (string).` error. Not sure why your answer has been upvoted :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need conditional logic for when `url` is empty, `for_each` can take care of it:

```
locals {
  url = {
    "https://url1" = { alarm_name = "url1 down", period = "120", threshold = "1", evaluation_periods = "2" },
    "https://url2" = { alarm_name = "url2 down", period = "120", threshold = "1", evaluation_periods = "2" },
    "https://url3" = { alarm_name = "url3 down", period = "120", threshold = "1", evaluation_periods = "2" }
  }
}

resource "aws_cloudwatch_metric_alarm" "url_down" {
  for_each            = var.aws_env == "env" ? local.url : {}
  alarm_name          = each.value.alarm_name
  ...
}
```

Comment: thanks that worked. I've been trying `var.aws_env == "env" ? local.url : 0` earlier and it didn't work of course.